# Evaluate a function with two lists and table

Tags: list-manipulation, table

I have the following function:

```
f[x_,y_]:=x^2/y
```

and two sample lists (that are actually longer):

```
x={2,4,6}
y={3,5,7}
```

I want to make a table of the form `{x,y,f}` where the pair `x`,`y` are the corresponding values of `x` and `y` paired at their respective positions; for example, `{2,3},{4,5},{6,7}`.

I tried using the next command:

```
Table[{i,j,f[i,j]},{i,x},{j,y}]
```

but I get a very big table (it is supposed my table should have only three rows, in this case). How could I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8):

**Using `Transpose` and `Join`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_, y_] := x^2/y
x = {2, 4, 6};
y = {3, 5, 7};

Transpose[{x, y}~Join~{f[x, y]}]
```

which can also be written as:

```
{x, y, f[x, y]} // Transpose
```

---

**Using `MapThread`:**

```
MapThread[{#1, #2, f[#1, #2]} &, {x, y}]
```

**Using `Inner`:**

```
Inner[{#1, #2, f[#1, #2]} &, x, y, List]
```

---

Other functional alternatives:

```
{First@#, Last@#, f[First@#1, Last@#]} & /@ Transpose[{x, y}]
```

---

```
{Sequence @@ #, f[Sequence @@ #]} & /@ Transpose[{x, y}]
```

---

Result:

> {{2, 3, 4/3}, {4, 5, 16/5}, {6, 7, 36/7}}

Answer (score 7):

For fun

[image]

[image]

```
☺ = {##, f @ ##}\[Transpose] &;

x~☺~y
```

> ```
>  {{2, 3, 4/3}, {4, 5, 16/5}, {6, 7, 36/7}}
> ```

```
☺☺ = {##2, # @ ##2}\[Transpose] &;

☺☺[f, x, y]
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 4/3}, {4, 5, 16/5}, {6, 7, 36/7}}
> ```

Comment: this works b/c `f` is composed of `Listable` operators (`Power` and `Divide`). Syed and Nasser's methods work for general `f`.

Answer (score 5):

One possible way

```
f[x_,y_]:=x^2/y
xVals={2,4,6};
yVals={3,5,7};
fVals=MapThread[f,{xVals,yVals}]
data = Transpose[{xVals, yVals,fVals}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And if you want to format into table, you could do

```
PrependTo[data, {"x", "y", "f(x,y)"}];
Grid[%, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_, y_] := x^2/y
x = {2, 4, 6};
y = {3, 5, 7};
```

Define a [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) function `g`;

```
g = Function[, {##, f @ ##}, Listable];
```

`g` takes both non-list and list arguments (list arguments should have the same length).

```
g[2, 3]
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 4/3}
> ```

```
g[x, y]
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 4/3}, {4, 5, 16/5}, {6, 7, 36/7}}
> ```

```
g[z, y]
```

> ```
> {{z, 3, z^2/3}, {z, 5, z^2/5}, {z, 7, z^2/7}}
> ```

```
g[x, w]
```

> ```
> {{2, w, 4/w}, {4, w, 16/w}, {6, w, 36/w}}
> ```

Comment: (+1) Nice, @kgrl! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is as follows:

```
f[pair : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}] := pair[[1]]^2/pair[[2]]
f[pair_?MatrixQ] := If[Last@Dimensions[pair] != 2, Map[f[#] &, Transpose@pair], Map[f[#] &, pair]]
```

Function test:

```
x = {2, 4, 6};
y = {3, 5, 7};
Table[{x[[i]], y[[i]], f[{x, y}][[i]]}, {i, 1, Last@Dimensions[{x, y}]}]

(*{{2, 3, 4/3}, {4, 5, 16/5}, {6, 7, 36/7}}*)
```

With your attempt:

```
Diagonal@Table[{i, j, f[{i, j}]}, {i, x}, {j, y}]

(*{{2, 3, 4/3}, {4, 5, 16/5}, {6, 7, 36/7}}*)
```

Or using @kglr's idea:

```
f[pair : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}] := {Sequence @@ pair, pair[[1]]^2/pair[[2]]}
f[pair_?MatrixQ] := If[Last@Dimensions[pair] != 2, Map[f[#] &, Transpose@pair], Map[f[#] &, pair]]

 (*{{2, 3, 4/3}, {4, 5, 16/5}, {6, 7, 36/7}}*)
```